# How to have compiler choose static array version of template over pointer?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to do something close to this:

```
template<typename TChar, size_t TSize>
inline size_t StringLength(TChar(&)[TSize])
{
    return TSize - 1;
}

template<typename TChar>
inline size_t StringLength(const TChar* value)
{
    return std::char_traits<TChar>::length(value);
}
```

...but when calling StringLength("abc"), the compiler finds it ambiguous:

```
test.cpp(15): could be 'size_t StringLength<char>(const TChar *const )'
with
[
    TChar=char
]
test.cpp(9): or       'size_t StringLength<const char,4>(TChar (&)[4])'
with
[
    TChar=const char
]
while trying to match the argument list '(const char [4])'
```

(This test was done in VS2013.)

I'd simply like to avoid the strlen when the size is available. Is there a way to do this, or a better option than what I'm attempting?

Comment: Is the answer 3 or 4? :-)

Comment: Heh, right, adjusted :)

Comment: Also, I'd like to avoid the "is this even a good idea?" line of conversation. Let's just assume this is going to be used in a specific context where we know the incoming char arrays are guaranteed null-terminated.

Comment: @2501: it's just StringLength("abc")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the pointer by const reference, which blocks the array-to-pointer conversion during template argument deduction:

```
template<typename TChar>
inline size_t StringLength(const TChar* const & value)
                                      //^^^^^^^
{
    return std::char_traits<TChar>::length(value);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b59cb19e140fff4).

Answer (score 2):

This way works:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename TChar, std::size_t TSize>
inline std::size_t StringLength(TChar(&)[TSize])
{
  return TSize;
}

template<typename TCharArray>                   // v-- using SFINAE to disable this overload if TCharArray is not an array type
inline std::size_t StringLength(TCharArray value, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_array<TCharArray>::value, void>::type * = nullptr)
{
  return std::char_traits<typename std::remove_pointer<TCharArray>::type>::length(value);
}


int main() {
  std::cout << StringLength("foo") << "\n";

  char const *ptr = "foo";

  std::cout << StringLength(ptr) << "\n";
}
```

...but are you sure this is a good idea? I know you want to avoid this discussion, but it's...hard. I mean, consider

```
char str[100] = "foo";

std::cout << StringLength(str); // will give 100.
```

It's not exactly POLA-compliant.

Comment: Regarding "is this a good idea", ok, fair point, and worth considering. What I'm mainly after is string literals passed in as parameters, and it's impossible to differentiate from a char array (which, as you note, could contain anything). I need to go through my use cases again. Overwhelmingly it's not char buffers, but that's not the same as a guarantee.